# Resigned app with bitcode enabled crashes at launch

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, code-signing, fastlane

When resigning an IPA with bitcode embedded using `sigh`, the resign process ends without errors but, after installing the IPA on a device using Xcode, the app **crashes at launch**. 
I cannot retrieve a crashlog from device, the only hint I have is this log from the `Console.app` on my mac.

```
Failed to start job for application<it.prima.prima>: <NSError: 0x15f21fa10; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
        RBLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:it.prima.prima[028c][rb-legacy];
    }
}
```

Which is not very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

After several atttempts I figured out that this happens only when resigning an app with bitcode embedded.

Removing bitcode support from project settings (`ENABLE_BITCODE = NO`) fixes the problem.